# Receiving HTML5 File with PHP (through XHR2)

Tags: android, html, post, cordova, xmlhttprequest

I'm starting with HTML5 and I'm finding troubles sending a file from HTML5 File API to PHP through XHR2. Here is the code (simplified):

Client javascript:

```
fs.root.getFile("test.mp3", {create: false, exclusive: false}, function(fileEntry) {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

  xhr.open("POST", "http://localhost/Server/?fileName=" + fileEntry.name);

  xhr.setRequestHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
  xhr.setRequestHeader("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");
  xhr.setRequestHeader("X-File-Name", fileEntry.name);

  xhr.send(fileEntry);
}, null);
```

Server PHP:

```
file_put_contents($_GET["fileName"], file_get_contents('php://input'));
```

I'm always receiving and creating a test.mp3 file with PHP, but inside the file there are:

```
[object Object]
```

instead the real mp3 content. The file exists in the file system of HTML5, and by the time it takes to upload, I think the entire content of the file is uploading, so maybe the problem is in the PHP code.

I tried to create a FormData object, but in Android with PhoneGap (now Cordova) it say FormData is not defined.

Thanks for your time, and sorry for my english ;P